# OleDbAdapter SelectCommand Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I want to query data from the only one sheet in Excel file.

```
 MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] ", MyConnection);
```

This line queries the data from Sheet1. The problem is that I don't know what's the name of the sheet in the input file. Is there any way I can write the command string so that it'll access the sheet no matter what the name is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Excel OleDb to get sheet names IN SHEET ORDER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164698/using-excel-oledb-to-get-sheet-names-in-sheet-order)

Comment: The idea is that I'll have only ONE sheet in the file. So, how can I select that sheet despite the name ?

Answer (score 1):

If you will **always** only have one sheet in the workbook, then you can do it by first getting the sheet name and then putting it into your query:

```
DataTable dt = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
```

If you have more than one sheet, then this will return the sheet that is first in **alphabetical order**.