# Can't Find Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to select the "Report Details" worksheet from my excel file. However, I am having trouble selecting it,

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Report Details'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

```
if (fileExtension == ".xls")
{
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
}
else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
{
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
}

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
con.Open();
DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Report Details]"; //ERROR HERE
dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
con.Close();
GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Viewing my "Tables" in the dataset viewer, the connection string is able to access the file. The Report Details column is displayed as 'Report Details$'. I have tried entering it that way, but I am still getting an error.

Comment: You don't show the connect string.  Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: what is the value of `filelocation`?

Comment: Maybe using dtExcelSheetName to get the real "TABLE NAME" for Worksheet

Comment: How would that be done...?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164698/using-excel-oledb-to-get-sheet-names-in-sheet-order

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

Your question title says `EXCEL/C# Cant Find Worksheet`

Your post says `I am trying to select the "Report Details" WORKSHEET from my excel file.`

The error you are getting is

`The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Report Details'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.`

**Solution**

You are missing a `$` sign

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Report Details$]";
```

Comment: I believe the '$ and 's are causing the error. I have tried it that way with no luck.

Comment: My code is not for the table it for the worksheet. :) Like I said I have tried and tested it. I addressed your main problem. But anyways you have found what you `actually` wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the tabel name throuh dtExcelSheetName

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[1][2].ToString() + "]";
```

It is working now.

Comment: This is not the actual reason for the error that you were getting `The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Report Details'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
`