# Order of sheets in Excel file while reading with GetOleDbSchemaTable

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I am using an ACE.OLEDB as below to read an excel file in C#. 
My Excel file has the following Sheets and in below order:

Sheet1, Sheet1 (2), Sheet2

The variable sheetName in my code takes 'Sheet1 (2)' as first sheet instead of 'Sheet1'.

My question is how does it determines the order of sheets?

```
string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
// Extra blank space cannot appear in Office 2007 and the last version. And we need to pay attention on semicolon.


using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    System.Data.DataTable sheetsName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] {null, null, null, "Table"});
    string firstSheetName = sheetsName.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    string sql = string.Format("select * from [{0}]", firstSheetName);
    OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connstring);
    DataSet set = new DataSet();
    ada.Fill(set);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f459200-deef-4131-be8a-1b67a41efb97/excel-sheet-names-in-sheet-order?forum=adodotnetdataproviders), the moderator says `I am afraid that OLEDB does not preserve the sheet order as they were in Excel.`.

While Googling though, I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164698/using-excel-oledb-to-get-sheet-names-in-sheet-order/#1165281) that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks icemanind for links.
So, if i know the order, then another solution could be hard code the sheet name like string sql = string.Format("select * from [{0}]", "Sheet1$"); right?

Comment: @Nish - Yes. I haven't tried this myself, but from what I've read, that seems correct.