# The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$_'

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb

I am reading data from an Excel file. when I read the normal Excel file,It works fine but when I read an excel file which has columns like shown below it does not find the work sheet and gives an exception-

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$_'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
>   [image]

My Code to read the excel is-

```
  private static DataTable getExcelData(string ExcelPath)
    {
        OleDbConnection con;
        string connectionString;
        string[] pathArray = ExcelPath.Split('.');
        var Extention = pathArray[pathArray.Length - 1];
        if (Extention == "xlsx")
            //read a 2007 file
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                ExcelPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        else
            //read a 97-2003 file
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                ExcelPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        DataTable dbSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null);
        var firstSheetName = dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"];
        OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + firstSheetName + "] Where NOT [Event Code]=''", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }

}
```

I have to get all the columns inside Mon,Tues etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetOleDbSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also returns hidden tables in your Excel file: usually a name like `Sheet1$_` indicates an hidden table created when you apply a filter on `Sheet1$`.

You need to change your code: search for table that ends with `$` to set `firstSheetName`.

Please note that [OLEDB does not preserve the sheet order as they were in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144407/order-of-sheets-in-excel-file-while-reading-with-getoledbschematable).

Also note that you need to do this to read an excel file with multirow titles:

- set `HDR=No` in `EXTENDED PROPERTIES` of your connection string
- specify column name and select range in your `OleDbCommand` in order to skip the first two rows

For example:

```
SELECT [F1] AS Location,
    [F2] AS EmpId,
    [F3] AS EmpName,
    [F4] AS MondayShift,
    [F5] AS Monday15Min,
    [F6] AS Monday30Min,
    [F7] AS Monday15Min2
FROM [Sheet1$A3:G]
```

Comment: yes I changed it to sheet1$ but I am not getting the Column names : "Shifts","15Min" etc. I have to get these in saperater datatable for eachday

Comment: this is a completely different question but... answer updated! ;)