# Make an array from all Excel worksheets

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I have a C# code that connects to Excel database via OpenFileDialog func. Excel file has too many worksheets and I would like to get all their names in one array and add them to combobox.
For example, this one is the first Excel document.
[image: Picture]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164698

Comment: Dearest, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, before asking your question do a research in SO database to find an anser so in this way, you avoid making duplicates questions. Thank you and at your service!

Comment: Excel is not a database. If you meant to get tables in Excel then look at OleDbConnection.GetSchema. Else you can simply loop the worksheets collection to get their names.

Comment: Have you heard of the Accord package? Maybe Accord.IO.ExcelReader will be of use to you, there is a way to take all the sheets and make them into a list I believe. if you want them as a string array let me know and Ill show you how to do that

Comment: That's pretty easy to do with the OpenXml SDK (well, for some definition of "easy")

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
Accord.IO.ExcelReader reader = new Accord.IO.ExcelReader("yourFile.xlsx");
string[] worksheets = reader.GetWorksheetList();
```

make sure to include

```
using Accord.IO;
```

which you can get Accord from NuGet by searching Accord and Accord.IO.

Then just fill in the items of the Combo box

```
foreach (string worksheet in worksheets)
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(worksheet);
}
```