# How capture an error like "Package Validation Error"

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis, event-handling, package

I what to read some Excel files put by users into a share folder. The issue occurs when the user changes the sheetname or changes the location in some rows or columns used to share data.

In this situation, SSIS show a Package Validation Error.

> Package Validation Error------------------------------Package Validation Error------------------------------ADDITIONAL
>   INFORMATION_Error at PackageName [SSIS.Pipeline]_ *Leer Staging Modelo
>   LS2* failed validation and returned validation status
>   _VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA_.Error at PackageName [SSIS.Pipeline]_ One or more component failed validation.Error at PackageName_ There were
>   errors during task validation.
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)------------------------------BUTTONS_OK------------------------------

Is possible to capture this kind of error using the event handler or other option to detect the errors?

Comment: One thing you could do is write something to validate the files BEFORE trying to import them.  Then handle the error that way and send email or something if the validation does not match what you expect.  You should be able to do this relatively easily (if you know c#) in an SSIS c# script task.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Event Handler for the `OnError` event of the Data Flow Task and read the error description from the System Variables `@[System::ErrorCode]` and `@[System::ErrorDescription]`:

- [System Variables for Event Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2017#system-variables-for-event-handlers)

If you want to learn more about Event Hanlders check the following article:

- [SSIS Event Handlers Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-event-handlers-basics)

---

**Update 1 - Workaround**

You can use a Script Task to check if this excel file exists or no using the `System.IO.File.Exists()` method.

Then you can use `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` library or `System.Data.Oledb` to check if the worksheet exists within the Excel file:

- [Using Excel OleDb to get sheet names IN SHEET ORDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164698/using-excel-oledb-to-get-sheet-names-in-sheet-order)
- [C# - Retrieve Excel Workbook Sheet Names.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names)

Comment: I tried with event Handler, put was not possible to catch the Package Valildation Error, another option??

Comment: @MarcosMorales please show what you tried. So i can help you

Comment: @MarcosMorales if you are looking for a workaround check my answer update