# How can show Excel Sheet Name in dropdownlist using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to show an excel sheet name in a dropdown list using c#. But using my code, I am able to show excel sheet name but excel sheet name comes with '' and $.
Coming Output is like: `Sheet1$`, `Sheet2$`

```
        sheetNameddl.Items.Clear();
        sheetNameddl.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        sheetNameddl.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME";
        sheetNameddl.DataValueField = "TABLE_NAME";
        sheetNameddl.DataBind();
        sheetNameddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Sheet--", ""));
```

But the wanted output is like `sheet1`, `sheet2`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. So, are you having problems retrieving the different Sheet names? Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165281/3563910) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetOleDbSchemaTable returns a DataTable. You can enumerate it and change the names (might need to do before you bind):

```
    sheetNameddl.Items.Clear();
    DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    foreach(DataRow ro in dt.Rows)
      ro["TABLE_NAME"] = ro["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().TrimEnd('$');
    sheetNameddl.DataSource = dt;
    sheetNameddl.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME";
    sheetNameddl.DataValueField = "TABLE_NAME";
    sheetNameddl.DataBind();
    sheetNameddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Sheet--", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is useful for me.