# How to read a range from an Excel sheet with a '#' in the name using OpenRowset property on SSIS?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, openrowset

I'm trying to read a range from an Excel sheet using the `OpenRowset` property in SSIS.

The sheet name is `IMSP#001` and I'm trying to access the range from cells `A2 to BA`.

I've tried setting the OpenRowset property as `IMSP#001$A2:BA` but I get the error

> 'Opening a rowset for "IMSP#001$A2:BA" failed'

I think the symbol `'#'` is the cause of the error.

I've also tried the query below but still get the same error.

```
SELECT * FROM [IMSP#001$A2:BA]
```

Comment: Try to store the name of the Excel file in a variable and check

Comment: I've tried that too but the error is the same.

Comment: how about getting sheet name via code and use that... GetOleDbSchemaTable. Look at the first answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164698/using-excel-oledb-to-get-sheet-names-in-sheet-order